# All Eigenvalues of the operator $L(v)= L^2(v).$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^n $ be a linear operator with the property $L(v)= L^2(v).$ Then find all the eigenvalues of the operator $L$.

### My attempt:

$L(v)= L^2(v)=L^3(v)=L^4(v)$ and so on.

So L has to define a matrix such that the result of any exponent on the matrix will result to the matrix itself. So, the matrix could be the identity matrix or any other matrix that satisfies this.

After this, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Well, you don't have enough information to determine the eigenvalues, but you **do** have enough information to determine the possible values of eigenvalues.

Comment: $L(v) = L^2(v)$ doesn't **define** the operator $L$, it's a property of $L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write down the eigenvalue equation:

$$Lv = \lambda v$$

Then apply what you know. On one hand:

$$
L^2 v = L(Lv) = L(\lambda v) = \lambda Lv = \lambda^2 v
$$

and on the other

$$
L^2 v = L v = \lambda v
$$

so that in particular, $\lambda^2 = \lambda$.

What possible solutions are there to this equation?

Comment: Considering real numbers, only 1 and 0?

Comment: That is correct (further, there are not other complex/imaginary solutions to this equation; $1$ and $0$ really are the **only** solutions.)

Comment: We can also say $\lambda^3 = \lambda$ and so there could be complex roots, right? This one gives -1 also.

Comment: That isn't an "alternative" equation though, it's an additional one; that is $\lambda$ must satisfy **all** such equations $\lambda^n = \lambda$ for any $n \geq 1$. So, while it is true that $\lambda^3 = \lambda$, since you also must have $\lambda^2 = \lambda$, you can't have $-1$ as a solution.

Comment: @TedMosby, Since the answer posted shows that it must be 0 or 1, your equation, which is also true, doesn't contradict that. -1 doesn't satisfy the quadratic so it's actually impossible, even though the cubic makes it a candidate.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $L$ with corresponding eigenvector $v \in \mathbf R^n$, then 
$$ \lambda v = L(v) = L^2(v) = \lambda^2 v \iff (\lambda^2 - \lambda)v = 0 \iff \lambda^2 - \lambda = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then there is $v\neq 0$ such that
$$
\lambda v=L(v)=L^2(v)=L[L(v)]=\lambda L(v)=\lambda^2 v\implies\lambda(1-\lambda)v=0.
$$
Because $v\neq 0$, this means $\lambda$ is either $0$ or $1$. An operator such that $L$ is called **idempotent**: $L=L^2$. The identity transformation is idempotent but there are non-identity idempotent transformations: let $X$ be $n\times k$ with full column rank, then you can verify that both
$$
P(X)\equiv X(X'X)^{-1}X',\quad M(X)\equiv I_n-P(X)
$$
are idempotent. Moreover, you check that $\text{rank}(P(X))=k$ and $\text{rank}(M(X))=n-k$. In particular, when $0<k<n$, $P(X)$ and $M(X)$ are not $I_n$, which has rank $n$.